# Powershell running in docker can not find SMB commands

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, acl, smb

I am trying to run Powershell in a docker container and then access an SMB share from there. But I can't run some PS commands to access the SMB share. The commands can not be found.

I run the PS continer by
`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/powershell`
The PS version is 7.3.4
But the conainer doesn't recognize SMb commands like `New-SmbGlobalMapping`, `New-SmbMapping`, `Get-Acl`, and etc.

[image]

Comment: Which PowerShell version do you run inside your container?

Comment: The result of the `$PSVersionTable` is

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.4
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.4
OS                             Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

Comment: Which OS do you run inside your container?

Comment: Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2